# 4 digit 7 segments display wrong number

Tags: arduino-uno, 7-segment

I'm an Arduino newbie having problems with 4 digit 7 segments display.
I want to display some thousands to 4 digit 7 segments display but it display only 0000.
I want to receive data from serial with string. And display the data to 4 digit 7 segments display... So test make String = '2575'... but it's not work.
What's wrong in my codes?
Any suggestions here will be a great help. thanks

```
int segments[] = {A0, A1, A2, A3};

byte digits[10][7] =
{
  { 1,1,1,1,1,1,0 }, // 0
  { 0,1,1,0,0,0,0 }, // 1
  { 1,1,0,1,1,0,1 }, // 2
  { 1,1,1,1,0,0,1 }, // 3
  { 0,1,1,0,0,1,1 }, // 4
  { 1,0,1,1,0,1,1 }, // 5
  { 1,0,1,1,1,1,1 }, // 6
  { 1,1,1,0,0,0,0 }, // 7
  { 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 }, // 8
  { 1,1,1,0,0,1,1 }  // 9
};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); 

  for(int i=2;i<10; i++) {
    pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
  }

  for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    pinMode(segments[i], OUTPUT);
  }
}

void loop() {
  String IncomingData = "2575";

  for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    digitalWrite(segments[i], LOW);
    int digit = atoi(IncomingData[i]);
    displayDigit(digit);
    delay(5);
    digitalWrite(segments[i], HIGH);
  }   
}

void displayDigit(int num){
  int pin = 2;
  for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
    digitalWrite(pin+i, digits[num][i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are  you sure you  have a common cathode display? Do you have current limit resistors on each segment pin?   Also, why do you have int for everything, when byte is all that is needed for a 0,1 or 0 to 9?  Try adding a Serial.print after this line int digit = atoi(IncomingData[i]); to see that digit is breaking out what you think it is.

Comment: use common anode display.  and int number display very well like displayDigit(5) but the code did not work... thanks

Comment: Code is setup for common cathode; low on the cathode to select the digit, high on the segments to turn them on.  If you are using common anode, then reverse the logic; high on the digit to select one, low on the segments to turn them on.

Comment: I use common cathode, sorry... and how can i fix it? Serial.print shows 00000000... I think use int for function displayDigit(int num)...

Comment: Fix it by reversing the logic:  High to turn on a digit, Low to turn it off. Flip all the 0s to 1s, the 1s to 0s in the digits array.

Comment: Change `displayDigit(digit);` to `displayDigit(3);` to see if the problem is in the string parsing, or in the led-displaying part.

Comment: displayDigit(3); works... string parsing problem... thanks

Answer (score 1):

You call `atoi()` with a char. Parameter of `atoi` is `const char*`. To convert ASCII code of digit to the digit use

`int digit = IncomingData[i] - '0'`

Comment: i can't understand that... anyway apply IncomingData[i] - '0' ... it's not works... thanks

Comment: @김태정, `int digit = IncomingData[i] - '0'`

Comment: you do not know what is ASCII code? how characters are encoded? or you don't know why IncomingData[i] is char and can't be used with `itoa`?

Comment: woww@.@ it works! thanks a lot! How can I understand the theory...! Have a nice day!

Comment: how can i accept the answer?...